# Adding hrefs to autogenerate data tables from firestore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to assign different hrefs to different tds within a table that autogenerates said tds from data pulled from firestore.

This is my oferta.js, I can retrieve the data from firestore without a problem but I don't really have any idea on how to assign a different href to the td "titulo", I tried using anchors but this results in establishing the same URL in each consecutive td, what can I do to circumvent this problem?, thanks in advance!

```
const ofertaList = document.querySelector('#ofertaLista');


const setupOferta = (data) => {

    let html = '';

    data.forEach(doc => {
      const oferta = doc.data();

      const td =`
        <tr>
          <td><a href="google.com">${oferta.titulo}</a></td>
          <td>${oferta.tipo}</td>
          <td>${oferta.fecha}</td>
          <td>${oferta.areaConocimiento}</td>
          <td>${oferta.cupoLimitado}</td>
        </tr>

      `;
      html += td

    });

    ofertaList.innerHTML = html;
}


db.collection('oferta').get().then((snapshot) =>{

 setupOferta(snapshot.docs)


});
```

EDIT

This is my oferta.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Oferta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bulma Version 0.8.x-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">


</head>

<body>

    <section class="hero is-info is-bold is-fullhd">
        <div class="hero-body">
            <nav class="navbar is-info">
                <a class="navbar-item" href="https://balsamiq.cloud/sb17nzh/p8yk3ts/r2278">
                    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
                </a>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <h1 class="title">
                            CAEDI
                        </h1>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </section>

   <div id="main">
         <section class="hero is-light">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        Oferta
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

 <div class="container">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="" id="textBoxSearch" placeholder="Buscar" />
      <br /><br />

    </div>

        <section class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="column is-12">
                        <div>
                        <table id="fullfeatures" class="table is-striped is-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="tr" >
                                    <th>Título</th>
                                    <th>Tipo</th>
                                    <th>Fecha</th>
                                    <th>Área de conocimiento</th>
                                    <th>Cupo limitado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="ofertaLista"></tbody>

                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </section>






    <footer class="footer has-background-info is-mobile is-fullhd">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-mobil">
                <div class="column is-half-fullhd">
                    <h1 class="title has-text-left">
                        Contacto
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="subtitle has-text-left">
                        Direccion, correo electronico, telefono
                    </h2>
                </div>
            <div class="column is-half-fullhd">
                    <h2 class="subtitle has-text-right">
                        Powered by (c) CAEDI
                    </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>



<script>

  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA0Rl0WAmrpfxPZsWwc_P-AiHg44K8e05c",
    authDomain: "caedi-fd241.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://caedi-fd241.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "caedi-fd241",

  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);




  const aut = firebase.auth();
  const db = firebase.firestore();


</script>

    <script async type="text/javascript" src="js/bulma.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bulma-modal-fx/dist/js/modal-fx.min.js"></script> 
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="js/oferta.js"></script>








</body>

</html>
```

[image]

This is the final result, I want to assign different hrefs to each "Titulo" but by doing this

`<td><a href="google.com">${oferta.titulo}</a></td>`

This happens

[image]

I want to put a href="historia.html" in "Historia del arte" and a href="matematicas.html" in "Matematicas 1", Is it possible?, sorry if I'm not expressing my self with clarity

Comment: I want to see data example of ${oferta.titulo}

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question but maybe you are looking for something like this?  ```<td><a href=`${oferta.link}`>oferta.titulo</a></td>```

Comment: Sure, I edited the question, thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><a href="${oferta.href}">${oferta.titulo}</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!, I'm a newbie where do I defined the url by using "href="${oferta.href}""

Comment: That information would have to come from the database itself. You would have to create a property on the database, with the name "href" that would then automatically come on the response from the API call. In other words, you need to create another column similar to Titulo, Tipo, Fecha ... but with the name href, then you will have it available I guess, but this depends on the code that gets the info from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the href of the element to be the variable for the URL:

```
      <td><a href="${thisIsSomeUrl}">${oferta.titulo}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
<td><a href="${oferta.href}">${oferta.titulo}</a></td>
```

or

```
<td><a href="http://your-domain.com/${oferta.data_id_or_any_other_field}">${oferta.titulo}</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm a newbie, when I use this method the url is not defined, how can I define it?, I'm not sure how that "${oferta.href}" works

Comment: no worries you can easily achieve this, you need to add one extra column to the database table from where you are getting all data. The column name will be "href" and then add values "historia.html in "Historia del arte" and
"matematicas.html" in "Matematicas 1" and so on....